# How to put content on the same line as a list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to make a little web layout. What I have so far [is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlIJa.png).

I'm trying to get the buttons on the same horizontal line as the navigation bar. In other words, I want the "display date" button directly to the right of the "home" navigation button. I can't change the margins on the buttons - it adjusts itself to the bottom border of the nav bar, as in, at a margin of 0 it's directly under the nav bar's bottom border (like you can see in the screenshot).

Sorry if the code is messy or hard to read, I'm at the very beginning level.

Here is the code for it -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <!-- *****CSS CODE START*****-->
        <style type="text/css">
            /*navigation bar*/
            ul {
                list-style-type:none;
                margin:50;
                padding:0;
            }
            a:link, a:visited {
                display:block;
                font-weight:bold;
                color:#dd731c;
                background-color:#473e36;
                width:120px;
                text-align:center;
                padding:4px;
                text-decoration:none;
                text-transform:uppercase;
            }
            a:hover, a:active {
                background-color:#bea792;
            }
            a:hover {
                color:black;
            }
            a:active {
                color:#dd731c;
            }
            /*button margins*/
            button.button1 {
                margin-top:0px;
                margin-bottom:10px;
                margin-right:50px;
                margin-left:200px;
            }
            button.button2 {
                margin-top:0px;
                margin-bottom:10px;
                margin-right:50px;
                margin-left:200px;
            }
            button.button3 {
                margin-top:0px;
                margin-bottom:10px;
                margin-right:50px;
                margin-left:200px;
            }
            /*line*/
            #middle hr.line {
                height: 1px;
                margin: 0 30px 5px 30px;
            }
            /*other*/
            body {
                background-color:#473e36;
            }
            h1 {
                color:orange;
                text-align:center;
            }
            p {
                font-family:"Times New Roman";
                font-size:20px;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- *****CSS CODE END***** -->
    </head>
    <!-- *****HTML CODE START***** -->
    
    <body>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <!-- line -->
        <hr class="line">
        <!-- navigation bar list -->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#news">News</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.google.com">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- buttons -->
        <button type="button" button class="button1" onclick="displayDate()">Display Date</button>
        <text id="demo">This is a paragraph.</text>
        <br />
        <button type="button" button class="button2" onclick="displayName()">Display Naaaame</button>
        <br />
        <button type="button" button class="button3" onclick="count()">count!</button>
        <text id="counter">0</text>
    </body>
    <!-- *****HTML CODE END***** -->




</html>
<!-- *****JavaScript CODE START***** -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentNum = 1;




    function displayDate() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
    }




    function displayName() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "jim";
    }




    function count() {
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = currentNum;
        currentNum = ++currentNum;
    }
</script>
<!-- *****JavaScript CODE END***** -->
```

Comment: Always get rid of all the code in your sample that has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: You should place your navigation bar (and other sections) into `div` tags to create sections on your page.

Comment: Sorry Seth, I wasn't sure which parts were important for this.

And JSW, I saw div tags but was a little confused about how they work - do they create a "scope" so I could, for example, use the same class name in 2 different div tags to refer to different things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `float:left` to your navigation `ul`.

Here, http://jsfiddle.net/6HVtq/

Comment: No problem. Cheers! And don't forget to put your sections in different divs. Thats the right way to go about stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Use float:left with your ul tag.Usually,this is not the proper way to achieve this.Put your list inside a div and then use float:left with that div.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to understand is CSS positioning and the difference between block-level elements vs. inline elements. Block-level elements have line breaks before and after them. ULs by default are block-level. Inline elements do not have this line breaking attribute. The button tags you are using are line. This should explain why when you added a button after your UL it appeared on a new row. But when you kept adding buttons they appeared horizontal to each other, and not on different lines. http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/block_vs_inline_elements.htm

You can fix this with CSS positioning. http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp Different positions will allow you to manipulate how your elements appear. You will want to be looking at the 'float' positions for this particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

Try using DIV tags and setup a grid system to controlling layout areas.  Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- *****CSS CODE START*****-->
<style type="text/css">

/*navigation bar*/
ul
{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:5;
  padding:0;
}
a:link,a:visited
{
  display:block;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#dd731c;
  background-color:#473e36;
  width:120px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:4px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
a:hover,a:active
{ 
  background-color:#bea792;
}

a:hover   {color:black;}
a:active  {color:#dd731c;}

/*button margins*/

button.button1
{
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 margin-right:50px;
 margin-left:5px;
}

button.button2
{
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-right:50px;
margin-left:5px;
}

button.button3
{
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 margin-right:50px;
 margin-left:5px;
}


/*line*/
 #middle hr.line{
 height: 1px;
 margin: 0 30px 5px 30px;
}

/*other*/
body {
 background-color:#473e36;
}
h1
{
 color:orange;
 text-align:center;
}

.grid-900
{
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;   
}

.grid-600
{
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right; 
}
 .grid-300
{
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  float: left; 
}
p
{
 font-family:"Times New Roman";
 font-size:20px;
 }


</style>
<!-- *****CSS CODE END***** -->
</head>

<!-- *****HTML CODE START***** -->
<body>

<h1>title</h1>

<div class="grid-900"> 
<div class="grid-300">
<!-- navigation bar list -->
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">About</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
<div class="grid-600">
         <button type="button" button class="button1" onclick="displayDate()">Display Date</button>
         <text id="demo">This is a paragraph.</text>
         <br />
         <button type="button" button class="button2" onclick="displayName()">Display Naaaame</button>
         <br />
         <button type="button" button class="button3" onclick="count()">count!</button>
         <text id="counter">0</text>

         <!-- line -->
        <hr class="line">
</div>
```

```
</body>
<!-- *****HTML CODE END***** -->
</html> 


<!-- *****JavaScript CODE START***** -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentNum=1 ;

function displayDate()
{
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date();
}

function displayName()
{
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= "jim";
}

function count()
{
  document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = currentNum;
  currentNum = ++currentNum;
}

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first remove your `display:block` for `a:link, a:visited` and add a style such as:

```
ul li{
   display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Thats not what he wants. He wants the buttons to be to the right of the navigation bar at the same horizontal level.